# PowerShell ISE WebRequest fails after multiple calls

Tags: powershell, web, httpwebrequest, webrequest, powershell-ise

The following code works by itself if running from a console, but when running it using PowerShell ISE, it fails with `Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The operation has timed out"` after two runs. Have to restart the ISE to run it again.

```
$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::CreateHttp("http://stackoverflow.com/")
$req.Timeout = 500
$req.GetResponse()
```

What is this limitation and is there a way to remove the limitation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have to *dispose* the response:

```
$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::CreateHttp("http://stackoverflow.de/")
$req.Timeout = 5000
$response = $req.GetResponse()

$response.Dispose()
```

However, there is a *built-in* [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) cmdlet `Invoke-WebRequest` which you could also use:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://stackoverflow.de/
```